# Question on bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty

I started 3 bounties recently. I am not the OP for any of them. I am looking for answers only from advaita perspective for each of the 3 questions. All 3 questions have advaita tags so I assumed that this is implicit. However, I want to make it more explicit for each bounty that answers are expected from advaita perspective only. Is there a way I can do that now?

Comment: Mods should be able to help you according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324104/editing-bounty-messages-is-it-finally-time-for-a-little-love-anti-doh-feat) MSE post.

Comment: Since OP also meant advaita as he used that tag then you may just edit the questions by adding a small note that "need answers from Advaita". I'm sure it doesn't change the original question.